# How to use alias correctly in `numpy`?

Tags: numpy

I am new to python.And finding some thing make me puzzle.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
b = a[3:6]
b[2] = 1000
print "a is "+ str(a)
print "b is "+ str(b)
```

the output is:

> a is [   0    1    2    3    4 1000    6    7    8    9]
>
> b is [   3    4 1000]

But in `MATLAB` or `Mathematica`,Changing b is not affect list a.

So What the purpose to design the alias in `numpy`?
Is it has some advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So What the purpose to design the alias in numpy? Is it has some advantage?

There are two possible advantages:

1. It saves space: `b` only takes a few dozen bytes regardless of how large a slice it refers to in `a`.  Imagine if `a` were 1 GB in size and `b` was half of it.
2. It enables in-place modifications.  This is precisely to call an advantage what you may see as a disadvantage (or surprise).

Note that NumPy is a somewhat low-level facility for array and matrix operations; the somewhat higher-level Pandas library would warn you if you try to modify a slice as in your example (specifically it would show `SettingWithCopyWarning`.  This warning is not always helpful--rather often it gets in the way of doing what we want to do.